# Stata: Count a variable by another one?

Tags: loops, count, max, stata

My little Stata Problem:

I have a table like this:

[image: My Data]

I want to create a variable that counts the number of different cat for each citing. This is... For the A citing there are 2 cat... the 3 and the 6. So I want another variable (`dif_cat`) with two 2.

For this sample it would look something like this:

[image: Example]

I have tried different methods I always feel like I am getting close but then I can't do it.
I tried `bysort` with `preserve` and `restore` but I don't seem to get there.

One attempt was:

```
egen tag = tag(cat citing) 
egen distinct = total(tag), by(citing)
```

Can you help me?

PS: I know this has nothing to do with Stata (but it may inspire someone) with an actually programming language I would try something such as: 
Having a cycle doing citing column and checking if equal to the one before
Having an auxiliary empty vector
Having a second cycle within the first that wouldsee if the current cat was in the vector and if not put it there.
When the citing changed I would count the lenght of the auxiliary matrix, reset it and do it again. The problem is that I need this in Stata code :S

Comment: Please show us your Stata code.

Comment: egen tag = tag(cat citing) 
egen distinct = total(tag), by(citing)

But doesn't quite work.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't quite work"? It works fine for your example data.

Comment: Cross-posted at http://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/45508-stata-count-distinct-values-of-a-variable-by-another-one It's courteous here, at a minimum, to make that clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way (from [Stata FAQ](http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/number-of-distinct-observations/)) is:

```
clear all
set more off

input ///
str1 citing cat
A 3
A 6
B 5
B 2
B 5
B 2
C 2
C 4
C 3
D 5
E 1
E 1
end

list, sepby(citing)

bysort citing cat: gen numvals = (_n == 1)
by citing: replace numvals = sum(numvals)
by citing: replace numvals = numvals[_N]

list, sepby(citing)
```

Comment: Works. Done.
Thanks Roberto.